# python matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the following code to create a polar plot of the sinus.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, .01)[1:]
plt.polar(theta, sin(theta))
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

but I want to plot it symmetrically, like this:

[image]

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Why do you define f()?

Answer (score 4):

The matplotlib polar allows for negative radius. So, if you want the symmetric plot you need to plot the absolute value of sin:

```
polar(theta, abs(sin(theta)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Anon, you need to plot the opposite of `sin(theta)`:

```
plt.polar(theta, sin(theta))
plt.polar(theta, -sin(theta))
```

[image]